# unlocked packages dependencies not working

Tags: salesforcedx

I am new to salesforce DX unlocked packages and have some issues with dependencies.

My current project json

```
{
  "packageDirectories": [
    {
      "path": "force-app",
      "default": true,
      "package": "package1",
      "versionName": "ver 0.1",
      "versionNumber": "0.1.0.NEXT",
      "dependencies": [
    {
      "package": "AzureManagementApi - 0.2.0.2"

    }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "namespace": "tpsle",
  "sfdcLoginUrl": "https://login.salesforce.com",
  "sourceApiVersion": "48.0",
  "packageAliases": {
    "HiringPortal": "0H...",
"    "AzureManagementApi - 0.2.0.2": "04t...."
  }
}
```

The package in the dependancy is to the specific version in my pacakage

My ProjectController:

```
     //Example
           @AuraEnabled
        public static List<ProjectClass> GetList(List<string> emailaddresses){
//Declare variables for http request to the management api
            AzureManagementApiClass amac = new AzureManagementApiClass();
            amac.Method = 'GET';
            HttpResponse response = AzureManagementApiController.Callout(amac);  

            if (response.getStatusCode() == 200) {
                List<ProjectClass> pclist = (List<ProjectClass>) JSON.deserialize(response.getBody(), List<ProjectClass>.class);
                //ProjectInfoClass pic = (ProjectInfoClass) JSON.deserialize(response.getBody(), ProjectInfoClass.class);
                return pclist;
            }
        }
```

MY AzureManagementApiController:

```
//Example
@namespaceAccessible
public class AzureManagementApiController {
    @namespaceAccessible
    public static HttpResponse Callout(AzureManagementApiClass amac){
        Http http = new Http();
        HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
```

//custom logic

```
        HttpResponse response = http.send(request);
        return response;    
    }
}
```

My AzureManagementApiClass

```
    @namespaceAccessible
public class AzureManagementApiClass {
    public string Path {get;set;}
    public string Method {get; set;}
    public integer TimeoutInMs {get;set;}
    public string SubscriptionKey {get;set;}
    public string RequestBody {get;set;}
    @namespaceAccessible
    public AzureManagementApiClass(){
    }

}
```

but it keeps failing. because the code give me an invalid from the apex class in de dependency

I updated my class already to the namespaceAccessible. But it keeps telling me : ProjectController: Variable does not exist: amac,ProjectController: Variable does not exist: amac,ProjectController: Variable does not exist: AzureManagementApiController,ProjectController: Invalid type: AzureManagementApiClass,ProjectController: Variable does not exist: amac,ProjectController: Variable does not exist: amac,ProjectController: Variable does not exist: amac,ProjectController: Variable does not exist: amac,ProjectController: Variable does not exist: AzureManagementApiController,ProjectController: Invalid type: AzureManagementApiClass,ProjectController: Variable does not exist: amac,ProjectController: Variable does not exist: amac,ProjectController: Variable does not exist: amac,ProjectController: Variable does not exist: amac,ProjectController: Variable does not exist: AzureManagementApiController,ProjectControllerTest: Dependent class is invalid and needs recompilation:
 Class ProjectController : Invalid type: AzureManagementApiClass,ProjectController: Invalid type: AzureManagementApiClass

Comment: @vinent welcome to Salesforce StackExchange. Could you add more details like sample reproducible code that we can reproduce this error?

Comment: Try to follow answer I have given before here https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/292046/18079

Comment: In your dependencies you should replace the version Id with the package alias = HiringPortal and on the packageAliases you should bind it the version Id and not package Id like you did

Comment: @MohithShrivastava i updated the question. Hope this clarrifies the question

Comment: @sfdxbomb thank's for your reply. I updated the code. And in my example. But the same issue occours.

Comment: Are you manage to deploy this code without an issue? Seems like your error describes an invalid type ‘“amac”. Make sure your code is deployable and tested before packaging it. Also if you still have issues describe what is the unlock package name you generate and which is the dependency- in order to validate your project.json is referencing the dependency correctly